# Tensor flow, making predictions using a trained network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

So I am training a network to classify images in tensor flow.  After I trained the network I began work on trying to use it to classify other images. The goal is to import an image, feed it to the classifier and have it print the result. I am having some trouble getting that part off the ground though.  Here is what I have so far. I found that having tf.argmax(y,1) gave an error.  I found that changing it to 0 fixed that error.  However I am not convinced that it is actually working.  I tossed 2 images through the classifier and they both got the same class even though they are vastly different.  Just need some perspective here.  Is this valid?  Or is there something wrong here that will always feed me the same class (in this case I got class 0 for both of the images I tried).

Is this even the right way to approach making predictions in tensor flow?  This is just the culmination of my debugging, not sure if it is what should be done or not.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
   X_train,X_validation,y_train,y_validation=train_test_split(X_train,y_train,   test_size=20,random_state=0)   
X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)




def LeNet(x):    
    # Arguments used for tf.truncated_normal, randomly defines variables 

for the weights and biases for each layer
    mu = 0
    sigma = 0.1

# SOLUTION: Layer 1: Convolutional. Input = 32x32x3. Output = 28x28x6.
conv1_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5, 5, 3, 6), mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
conv1_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(6))
conv1   = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv1_W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + conv1_b

# SOLUTION: Activation.
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)

# SOLUTION: Pooling. Input = 28x28x6. Output = 14x14x6.
conv1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')

# SOLUTION: Layer 2: Convolutional. Output = 10x10x16.
conv2_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5, 5, 6, 16), mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
conv2_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(16))
conv2   = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, conv2_W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID') + conv2_b

# SOLUTION: Activation.
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)

# SOLUTION: Pooling. Input = 10x10x16. Output = 5x5x16.
conv2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')

# SOLUTION: Flatten. Input = 5x5x16. Output = 400.
fc0   = flatten(conv2)

# SOLUTION: Layer 3: Fully Connected. Input = 400. Output = 120.
fc1_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(400, 120), mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
fc1_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(120))
fc1   = tf.matmul(fc0, fc1_W) + fc1_b

# SOLUTION: Activation.
fc1    = tf.nn.relu(fc1)

# SOLUTION: Layer 4: Fully Connected. Input = 120. Output = 84.
fc2_W  = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(120, 84), mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
fc2_b  = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(84))
fc2    = tf.matmul(fc1, fc2_W) + fc2_b

# SOLUTION: Activation.
fc2    = tf.nn.relu(fc2)

# SOLUTION: Layer 5: Fully Connected. Input = 84. Output = 43.
fc3_W  = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(84, 43), mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
fc3_b  = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(43))
logits = tf.matmul(fc2, fc3_W) + fc3_b

return logits



import tensorflow as tf
 x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32, 3))
 y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
 one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(y, 43)
EPOCHS=10
BATCH_SIZE=128

rate = 0.001

logits = LeNet(x)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, one_hot_y)
loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = rate)
training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_y, 1))
accuracy_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
saver = tf.train.Saver()

def evaluate(X_data, y_data):
    num_examples = len(X_data)
    total_accuracy = 0
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_x, batch_y = X_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE], y_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE]
        accuracy = sess.run(accuracy_operation, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        total_accuracy += (accuracy * len(batch_x))
    return total_accuracy / num_examples


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_examples = len(X_train)

    print("Training...")
    print()
    for i in range(EPOCHS):
        X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
        for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
            end = offset + BATCH_SIZE
            batch_x, batch_y = X_train[offset:end], y_train[offset:end]
            sess.run(training_operation, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        validation_accuracy = evaluate(X_validation, y_validation)
        print("EPOCH {} ...".format(i+1))
        print("Validation Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(validation_accuracy))
        print()

    saver.save(sess, './lenet')
    print("Model saved")


import cv2
image=cv2.imread('File path')
image=cv2.resize(image,(32,32)) #classifier takes 32X32 images 
image=np.array(image)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver3 = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./lenet.meta')
    saver3.restore(sess, "./lenet")
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    predictions = sess.run(tf.argmax(y,0), feed_dict={x: image})
    print (predictions)
```

Comment: What's going on with `pred`? Is it used anywhere? And assuming `y` has logits or softmax output, you could eval and print that directly (it should definitely change based on the image, the label might just be a coincidence).

Comment: I tried this method  predictions = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: image}) and got an error. "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_4' with dtype float".  I seem to have forgotten to delete it.

Comment: Are you running this interactively (ipython/jupyter)? That often leads to floating placeholders. If not, have you declared any placeholders other than `x`? Not much else I can say without looking at the model itself.

Comment: for reference y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None)), so I am pretty sure I've done nothing.

Comment: Yes, it is running in jupyter.  I'll amend the post with the whole model.

Comment: Oh. I thought these were Tensors which mirrored the graph you were loading. Can you just figure out the names instead and do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829641/tensorflow-train-import-meta-graph-does-not-work/38834095#38834095)?

Comment: Ah, y is supposed to be the label which gets fed in to evaluate. So no, you don't want to take the argmax of that. Can you print out `logits` based on the fed image? That's what you want to take the argmax of to find the most likely predicted label. Try running it from scratch to avoid the floating placeholder problem.

Comment: I just am giving re running the whole notebook from scratch a try but this should work right?       pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    classification = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: image_array})

Comment: Yeah that did it, for the record it returns an array of the softmax functions. Thanks so much for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

So what had to happen here was first clear the kernel and outputs. Somewhere along the way my placeholders got muddled up and clearing the kernel fixed that right up.  Then I had to realize what really had to get done here: I had to call up the `softmax` function on my new data.

Like this:

```
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
classification = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: image_array})
```