# How to import a model in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having difficulties restoring a saved model. I am training a CNN on the MNIST dataset, all according to the MNIST tutorial on [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) and I am saving my model with the following code:

```
saver.save(sess, './Tensorflow_MNIST', global_step=max_steps)
```

This creates the following files:

- Tensorflow_MNIST-1000.data-00000-of-00001
- Tensorflow_MNIST-1000.index
- Tensorflow_MNIST-1000.meta
- checkpoint

Later on I want to load the model and continue training with:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./Tensorflow_MNIST-1000.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, './Tensorflow_MNIST-1000')

batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict[x: batch_xs, y_batch_ys, keep_prob:0.5])
```

This however returns an error:

```
NameError: name 'train_step' is not defined
```

So it seems like the graph and its variables and operations are not loaded properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

when save:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(...variables...)
# Remember the training_op we want to run by adding it to a collection.
tf.add_to_collection('train_step', train_step)
```

when restore :

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  ....

  # tf.get_collection() returns a list. get the first one
  train_step = tf.get_collection('train_step')[0]
  sess.run(train_step, ....)
```

if you want to re-use the model, I think changing `sess.run(train_step...)` to 
`train_step(...)` should work

Answer (score 1):

When using `saver.save()` TensorFlow saves the computational graph, which is made of Tensors i.e. TensorFlow's object.

It will not save **every** variables you used. In particular, anything that is **not** a `tf.Tensor` won't be saved.

You may want to have your own data structure to save any other infomation.

You could use JSON format for convenience or even `pickle` that is really straightforward to use in python, but not to edit by hand.

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Calling all tensors with "" and :0 added as described at [import meta_graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829641/tensorflow-train-import-meta-graph-does-not-work/38834095#38834095) seems to do the trick. So for example, the call to calculate the accuracy becomes:

```
test_accuracy = sess.run("accuracy:0", feed_dict={"x:0": mnist.test.images, "y_:0": mnist.test.labels, "keep_prob:0": 1.0})
```