# How to restore a TensorFlow session for query without having to declare the variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been searching for the solution for this over the Internet but couldn't find a way to do it on Python.

What I need to do is this: I have several different TensorFlow models trained to perform the same task; these models have different structures but share the same interface for doing queries - on the C++ API, I can do this

```
 Status status = session_->Run(feed_dict, {"output_I_want"}, {}, &outputs);
```

for all these models without problem.

However when I try to do the same thing with Python, it seems all the save/restore tutorials I can find online require that I first declare the variables used in the model before trying to restore. In my project I only need to use the model as a blackbox and would only need to query with this [feed_dict -> output] way. I was wondering if there are ways to do that with Python.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834095/15791) as a practical example of [saving and restoring a metagraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph). This should answer the second half of your post, if you combine this with the checkpoint all you probably need in your use-case is convention on naming the inputs and the outputs.