# Tensorflow: checkpoint files are getting deleted at the end of training without any error message

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition

I was following this link to train audio recognition model. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition

Started with the command:

```
python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py
```

End of the command shows :

> INFO:tensorflow:Saving to
>   "/media/slattann/HDD2/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000"
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Confusion Matrix:
>
> ```
>  [[257   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
>  [  0 194   4   3   4   7   8  16   5   0   7   9]
>  [  0   4 239   1   3   0   6   2   0   0   1   0]
>  [  1   4   0 216   1   6   3   4   1   0   3  13]
>  [  0   0   0   0 257   0   2   1   3   1   6   2]
>  [  2   7   0  13   3 213   2   0   1   0   1  11]
>  [  0   2  11   0   5   0 246   3   0   0   0   0]
>  [  1  11   0   1   1   1   0 240   1   2   1   0]
>  [  1   7   0   0   1   0   1   2 234   0   0   0]
>  [  1   4   0   0  19   0   1   2   9 222   3   1]
>  [  0   2   1   0   7   1   1   0   1   0 235   1]
>  [  0   6   0  33   5   3   6   2   0   0   2 194]]
> ```
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Final test accuracy = 89.2% (N=3081)

but i could not find this checkpoint file.
at the end I could only see:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Files I could see in the /media/slattann/HDD2/tmp/speech_commands_train folder:

```
checkpoint
conv.ckpt-17600.data-00000-of-00001
conv.ckpt-17600.index
conv.ckpt-17600.meta
conv.ckpt-17700.data-00000-of-00001
conv.ckpt-17700.index
conv.ckpt-17700.meta
conv.ckpt-17800.data-00000-of-00001
conv.ckpt-17800.index
conv.ckpt-17800.meta
conv.ckpt-17900.data-00000-of-00001
conv.ckpt-17900.index
conv.ckpt-17900.meta
conv.ckpt-18000.data-00000-of-00001
conv.ckpt-18000.index
conv.ckpt-18000.meta
conv_labels.txt
conv.pbtxt
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am blocked to proceed with freezing the graph stage before creating the tensorflow model(.pb).

[image]
      [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIXZX.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIXZX.jpg

Answer (score 1):

When it says `Saving to "/media/slattann/HDD2/tmp/speech_commands_train/conv.ckpt-18000"` what it really means is that it creates (at least) **three files with the same prefix**:

- conv.ckpt-18000.meta (containing the meta-graph definition)
- conv.ckpt-18000.index
- conv.ckpt-18000.data-00000-of-00001 (containing the actual variables' data, possibly sharded).

To `freeze_graph` just pass the prefix `path/to/checkpoint/dir/conv.ckpt-18000` , it will handle the rest on its own.

For more informatoin about *why* there are three files in the first place, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265035/tensorflow-why-there-are-3-files-after-saving-the-model)

Comment: I could able to start freezing the graph but failed with error:
-----
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-02-27 22:48:14.098664: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_tensor.cc:170 : Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for 
---
Does this error mean I need to compile Tensorflow first? Can you please share the command to do so. Thanks
Sameer Lattannavar

Comment: The error has likely a different source. What's the error message?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you have Tensorflow already installed, so no need to compile it. Try changing the checkpoint_name argument of `freeze_graph` to the full name of the `.data` file and see if the error changes

Comment: Tensorflow what I am using is git cloned one. after git clone next step I tried was train model to generate checkpoints.
So if I have to compile what are the commands to do so? Thanks

Comment: That's very complex and not describable in one comment (and beyond the scope of this question). Start here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ and read through the documents, there they explain how to install tensorflow, or build it yourself if that's really what you want (which probably isn't).