# AI Platform restore checkpoint not working in estimator train_and_evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am using AI Platform to train a Tensorflow model using the Estimator API. However, when the model saves a checkpoint and attempts to restore the checkpoint, it throws the error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for gs://path/keras/keras_model.ckpt`

It appears that this is an issue with restoring the metadata graph in Tensorflow, which is code that goes in the session setup ([TensorFlow, why there are 3 files after saving the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265035/tensorflow-why-there-are-3-files-after-saving-the-model)). However, since AI Platform abstracts this away from my configuration, how can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it appears that at the start of each new job run, the job directory from the previous run is not deleted (on purpose, so I can have multiple workers train at the same time). If the previous run failed, some checkpoints aren't stored properly and this causes problems for AI Platform.