# Problem with restoring checkpoint in tensorflow (op type not registered error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to finetune a pretrained Inception V3 network.
To restore the latest checkpoint, I am following the great answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273348/13608754

### My code is:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(f'{p}/model.ckpt.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, f'{p}/model.ckpt')
```

### Content of path `p`:

- model.ckpt.index
- model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt.meta

This, as I understand, should work.

### The Error:

The error I am getting is in the func `c_api.TF_GraphImportGraphDefWithResults` from `tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py`:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Op type not
> registered 'OptimizeDatasetV2' in binary running on DL-2. Make sure
> the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this
> process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops
> from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be
> done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered
> when the module is first accessed.

Does anyone understand what should I do? If more information is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, my guess is that the model is supposed to be loaded with the current version of TF (2.0+) yet you are explicitly importing the legacy v1 branch of TF, do you have a good reason to do this?

The answer you are referencing applies to the old version of TF (v1). In the current version (TF 2.0+) to load a pretrained model use [tf.keras.models.load_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model):

```
import tensorflow as tf

p = 'path/to/model/folder/'
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(p)
```

(also notice you pass the path to the folder that contains the model files)

Comment: Hi,
I tried running your script with `p` being both the folder within which the files are stored (the model.ckpt.... files) and also the files' paths themselvs. All failed with: "SavedModel file does not exist at: /home/yonatan/Desktop/models/wes/model.index/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}"

Comment: Yes, I did not realize that the file names you're presenting actually match the TensorFlow v1 checkpoint. Do you know the TF version in which a given model was trained? I would install the same version and then try again. If you don't know, I'd try the last TF 1.x version.